# How to change a nested list's list into a string?

Tags: python

For example, if my nested list is:

```
[['2HC'], ['4BB'], ['4BB'], ['2HC']]
```

How would I have the `['2HC']`'s refer to `'A'` and the `['4BB']`'s refer to `'B'`, so that my result would be:

```
['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```

Comment: Have you tried any script atall? if so can you post it here?

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [['2HC',], ['4BB'], ['4BB'], ['2HC']]
mapping = {'2HC' : 'A', '4BB': 'B'}

new_list = [mapping[i[0]] for i in l]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [['2HC'], ['4BB'], ['4BB'], ['2HC']]
d =  {'2HC' : 'A', '4BB': 'B'}

map(lambda x: d[x[0]], l)
# ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [['2HC'], ['4BB'], ['4BB'], ['2HC']]

lst = ['A' if x[0] == '2HC' else 'B' for x in l]

print(lst)
```

**Output**

```
['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the list to make it easier, and then use a simple translation mapping:

```
from itertools import chain

nested_vs = [['2HC'], ['4BB'], ['4BB'], ['2HC']]

# flatten
vs = chain.from_iterable(nested_vs)

# translate
translations = {'2HC' : 'A', '4BB': 'B'}
translated = list(map(translations.get, vs))
```

Now `translated` holds:

```
['A', 'B', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 0):

An `itertools` solution for this problem-

```
data = [['2HC',], ['4BB'], ['4BB'], ['2HC']]
mapping = {'2HC' : 'A', '4BB': 'B'}
l = [mapping[i] for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(data)]
```

Benefit of `itertools` is it will convert the list data to flat list even if the inner list contains more than one element.

For example if list `data` was -

`[['2HC', '2HC'], ['4BB'], ['4BB'], ['2HC']]`

we would still get the right output.